# which is the best layout for the given image?

Tags: android, layout

I Want to create a Layout as given in the image. Each box will contain an imageview(13 imagviews). I tried using table layout.But I could not stretch the first and last cell to the entire screen length. Is there any way to stretch a cell or should i use someother layout? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoQ9b.png

Comment: use a custom listview

Comment: do you want it scroll enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats so simple. first use a RelativeLayout that will hold all your views, then inside it just use RelativeLayout for outer 4 sections. for remaining 9 inner sections you can either use RelativeLayout or LinearLayout or TableLayout or GridLayout as per it suits to you...

It would hardly take 10-15 minutes.

Comment: Thank You:) Your idea helped and I did it. And I do not have enough reputation to vote up. :(